# React native notifications

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am working on a react-native project (using CRNA) and am to the point where I want to develop push notifications for various features. Does anyone have any suggestions on what library I should use. I've been told that it is typically something rather difficult to get up and running so some light-weight out of the box solution would be great. BTW, I am using Expo for dev environment. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't you just use their library? https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications.html && https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications.html#push-notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Expo I think push-notifications are already [configured](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications.html). Otherwise I suggest using [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm). It's easy to implement, it works fine in my project both for Android and iOS. I tried other libraries but only this one worked for me.

Comment: This package is no longer maintained; not recommended for future visitors.